# How to test a mobile deep links from App/Play Store in a Flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, store, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a mobile app (developed with Flutter but not relevant for this question).

The app uses [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) functionality to bring the user inside and activate some functionalities.
I tried to activate the link with the app already installed on the device and it works nicely. Now I want to test if the DL works also if passing from the App/Play Store, but since the app is not released yet I can't figure how to do that.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have built you app on release mode and installed on a device and worked, It should be the same behavior on the app downloaded from Play Store

Comment: yes, but my question was: How can I test the behavior passing from the store? not with the app already installed. There must be a way to test before releasing, without just assuming that it should work

Comment: Well, you have several channels for this on play console. There's a testing track called "internal testing", there you can upload your app just for you and test your deep links.
Of corse you'll need a developer account.

Comment: @AleTheFe for ios, you have TestFlight which is basically the same, you upload your app for you or you and your team, and you can download your app and test it on iOS

Comment: OK, so test channels on Android and TestFlight for iOS work! got it, thanks!

Comment: Nice! Good luck pal!